# Connection to local switch via Mikrotik router jumphost using Ansible

Tags: ansible, mikrotik, jumphost, bastion

I am using Ansible on my Debian client machine.
I am trying to setup inventory file and ansible playbook for showing simple version of local devices from remote site that is behind NAT by using jumphost (bastion) which is my mikrotik/routeros using ssh called "jumphost" and then connect to final local mikrotik routeros switch called "localswitch"
I get the following error:
"msg": "ssh connection failed: ssh connect failed: Socket error: Connection reset by peer"

Please help by using ansible_ssh_common_args for routeros as jumphost

inventory.yaml

```yaml
all:
  switches:
    hosts:
      localswitch.company.local:
        vars:
          ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q myuser@jumphost.company.com"'
```

playbook.yaml:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    ansible_network_os: routeros
  tasks:
    - name: Print RouterBoard version
      routeros_command:
        commands:
          - /system routerboard print
      register: result

    - name: Display command output
      debug: 
        var: result.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score -1):

It feels like its not picking up the variable and know to use it correctly. Here is another example to try:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -p 2222 -W %h:%p -q username@bastion.example.com"'
```

Is the SSH port as well open to the device? Have you tried to add the variable at the playbook level or inventory level and see if it works that way?

[see also](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/using-ansible-playbook-ssh-bastion-jump-host)